# Measuring time of @Async annotated method's execution with the asprctj

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, aspectj

How I can measure time of @Async annotated method's execution with the help of aspectj in spring boot program

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this thing in following ways. 
You just need to write around aspect for calculating time against a specific function.

Following is the code:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class AsynMethodTimeAspect {

@Around(value = "@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async)")
    public Object logTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        String myClassname = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getSimpleName() + " : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();


        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        log.info(myClassname + "." + method + " - end - " + elapsedTime + "ms");
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me, because the aspect interception of method performs at main thread and actually method execution at on of TaskExecutorPool thread, so main thread delegate execution to that thread and exit from method with elapsedTime near 1ms